# {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one *Class Library* project that is imported by a *Asp.net* project.

The Class Library project I'm importing the library *Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face*.

I build and launch my asp.net project with any problem but when I try to access a function that uses classes form the library *Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face* I got the following error:

> {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at FaceSimilarity.FaceSimilarity.GetSimilarity(Image mainImage, List`1 images, Double minimumPercentage) at GAM.Controllers.DonorController.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ISEP\Repository\LABDSOFT\Project\GAM\GAM\Controllers\DonorController.cs:line 79 }

I had tried the following steps without any success:

1. Clean and build the class library project and the *asp.net* project
2. Re-install the library *Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face*

**[Edit]**

I'm sure that I have the last versions of the libraries.

Comment: Looks like you might be using an old library.  Have you tried https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/?  Sorry for just the link but if you look quick it may still be valid.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns I'm sure that I have the last version of the library.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982032/bitness-issue-32bit-vs-64bit

Comment: Did you solve the issue ? Please do post the solution here. I am facing a similar issue.